# python lockf and flock behaviour

Tags: python, file-locking, flock, fcntl

I have read enough posts on stackoverflow regarding the difference between `flock`/`lockf`/`fcntl` but I am unable to answer the below observation:

```
>>> import fcntl
>>> a = open('/tmp/locktest', 'w')
>>> b = open('/tmp/locktest', 'w')
>>> fcntl.lockf(a, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
>>> fcntl.lockf(a, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
>>> fcntl.lockf(b, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
>>>
>>> a.close()
>>> b.close()

>>> a = open('/tmp/locktest', 'w')
>>> b = open('/tmp/locktest', 'w')
>>> fcntl.flock(a, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
>>> fcntl.flock(a, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
>>> fcntl.flock(b, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Why is the behaviour different in the two cases? I know the obvious answer that these are two different locking mechanisms. I am looking for:

1. What actually `lockf()` or `flock()` does to file (`inode/fd`)?
2. As per the demo, are we allowed taking the same lock recursively?

I understand the basics of `fds` and stuff so I would prefer to have a technical answer with more insights to operating system level details.

OSX 10.9.3, Python: 2.7.5

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit the question to actually include a question. Please review and edit if that's not what you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: @NPE: It was part of my first sentence though its better to have it explicitly put there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

A nice article about this:
[On the Brokenness of File Locking](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/locking.html)

In short:

- POSIX locks:

  > lockf() most of the time implemented as just an interface of fcntl()
  >
  > fcntl() locks are bound to processes, not file descriptors. **If a process has multiple open file descriptors for a particular file, any one of these file descriptors used for acquiring locking will *RESET* the lock.**
- BSD lock:

  > flock() locks are bound to file descriptors, not processes.

### Furthermore

A good analysis with tests:
[Advisory File Locking – My take on POSIX and BSD locks](http://loonytek.com/2015/01/15/advisory-file-locking-differences-between-posix-and-bsd-locks/)

Excerpt of Summary:

> - fcntl and flock style locks are completely orthogonal to each other. Any system providing both(Linux does) will be treating locks obtained through each one of them independently.
> - Both POSIX and BSD locks are automatically released when the process exits or is aborted.
> - Both POSIX and BSD locks are preserved across execve calls except when the process has set FD_CLOEXEC flag forcing the file descriptor to be closed, and not inherited by the new process.

Comment: A fair assessment. It should be emphasized that **POSIX locks silently fail under multithreading scenarios** and should (*arguably*) be considered harmful for use in modern software stacks – [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) notwithstanding. More critically, it should be emphasized that **both POSIX and BSD locks on group- or world-readable files pose an extreme security risk.** Why? Because *any* user with read permissions for the file to be locked can permanently deadlock your Python application by preemptively acquiring that lock first and then never releasing it.

Comment: **tl;dr:** **(A)** in-memory locks (e.g., [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) synchronization primitives) are strongly preferable to both BSD- and POSIX-style locks, **(B)** BSD-style `flock` locks are strongly preferable to POSIX-style `fcntl` locks, and **(C)** neither BSD- nor POSIX-style locks should be used unless permissions for the file(s) to be locked are strictly constrained to at most `0600`.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this answer is to note that you're using the `fcntl.LOCK_NB` flag.  If you remove this flag, then your second case will block instead of raising an exception.

Comment: Also, if you run another python session, in another window, and use lockf() on the file and leave the file open, then you'll find the exception occurs in the first call to `fcntl.lockf()`, in your second session (if we're back to using `fcntl.LOCK_NB`).  This confirms that the state of `fcntl.lockf()` process-global, while the state of `fcntl.flock()` is scoped by the file descriptor.

Comment: Regarding @CecilCurry's link, notice that Python multiprocessing module is *only* applicable to synchronize *Python subprocesses spawned by a common parent*, and if one of the process crashes [this leaks semaphores and shared memory segments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-start-methods) and [corrupts Queue objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) and [pipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.recv_bytes_into).

Comment: I would hope that [opening a file with `O_EXCL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33223732/1509695) is not relying on these locks, while my orientation into navigating linux source code is very lacking ...