# How to lock a folder?

Tags: python, locking, race-condition

Several instances of my script may want to clean up a folder called `logs`. I want to give access to one script at a time. If another script is in there just ignore the clean up and continue. My implementation is as follows:

```
lockfile = "LOCKED"
if not os.path.isfile(lockfile):
    open(lockfile, "a").close()

    # start clean up

    os.remove(lockfile)
```

Is this safe? I can imagine that the if statement evaluates to true before either script has created the lock file. Could this happen? How would you implement such a lock?

Comment: you could use a portable lock on your lock file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/490102/6451573

Comment: `if not os.path.isfile(lockfile):
    open(lockfile, "a").close()` is just unsafe because the file could be created after the if and before the open. At least try to open using os.open without CREAT and catch the exception

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre can you just write it out? not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean: when you test "isfile", it can NOT exist, then be created then you try to open. It's not atomic. Lookup "atomic file creation in python": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223564/atomically-creating-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist-in-python

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I would like to write up an answer using your suggestion but I can't because the question is marked as duplicate

Comment: if the answer is just copying one of the duplicates, then no need to write an answer. If the answer takes bits of stuff & adds something new, I'm ok to reopen. Maybe you could [edit] your question to explain how the duplicates _don't_ answer your question. Then the question is automatically placed in the reopen queue and you don't even need my advice.